# Access port keeps changing to trunk port

Tags: cisco

I have a cisco Sf250 Switch, all are working fine except one port. I have made it to work as a access port but it keeps changing to Trunk port over time. I have switched ports but to no avail.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Do you have any macros assigned to that int? I have SG300s and I think `no macro auto smartport` kept it from doing that. If there's a phone hooked up to the int it may go into trunk mode automatically. My experience with the SG300 is little, and null for yours.

Comment: Can you include the configuration in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Also try `switchport nonegotiate`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "no" form of the command to remove the trunk configuation. You need to configure "switchport mode access" to change it from trunk to access mode.

- interface fa0/1
- switchport mode access
- no switchport trunk encapsulation -
- dot1q

Hope this helps.